# SQL Most efficient way to create int value from dateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a trigger which updates a field AFTER UPDATE.   It inserts the date for each of the updated rows.  This line in the trigger does this action:

```
SET t.lastUpdatedDateTime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Using  yyyymmddhhmmss the above line will insert this 2015-07-16 16:19:00.  Now I have a situation where the business wants an integer version of this.

What is the most effective way to achieve this.  This is what I have which does work but it seems very long and expensive:

```
SET t.lastUpdatedDateTimeINT = CAST('' + cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)) + right('0' + cast((month(GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((day(GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(hh, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(MI, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(ss, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2)  as bigint)
```

Is there a better more efficient way to do this? The desired outcome is 20150716161900

A secondary question.  I am not a fan of storing dates as integers at all.  in fact I have never done it before this current role.  Can I ask for opinions on this, what are great reasons to avoid this?  There are a few reasons why there is a preference for this in this organisation.  Here is one,  every time a client hit a webservice this dateTime value is delivered with the content, when the client hits the webservice in the future it need to pass in this dateTime value to effectivley get the best data back.  Simply, The business is afraid this will come back in a different format.

EDITED:

Here is the full trigger for completness:

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_lastUpdated]
    ON [dbo].[AAdeleteMe] 
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN 
        IF NOT UPDATE(lastUpdatedDateTime)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE t
                 -- my original code (the long way for my result)
                 --SET t.lastUpdatedDateTimeINT = CAST('' + cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar(4)) + right('0' + cast((month(GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((day(GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(hh, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(MI, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2) + right('0' + cast((datepart(ss, GETDATE())) as varchar(2)), 2)  as bigint)
                 --and here is the solution below (the shortway for my result)
                 --SET t.lastUpdatedDateTimeINT = REPLACE(REPLACE((convert(varchar(10),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,111) + convert(varchar(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)),'/',''),':','')
                --Just discovered the 112 format so managed to drop one replace
                SET t.lastUpdatedDateTimeINT = REPLACE((convert(varchar(10),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,112) + convert(varchar(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)),':','') 
                FROM dbo.AADeleteMe AS t 
                INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
                ON t.ID = i.ID;
        END
    END

    GO
```

Comment: you lose all the functionality of date-math and have to rewrite it. have fun using that. plus it is stupid.

Comment: Tell your business that that is a terrible reason.

Comment: "when the client hits the webservice in the future it need to pass in this dateTime value to effectivley get the best data back" then convert the datetime field to an integer in the webservice somehow. Don't store it as junk just because you want it presented in a certain way. What happens when you want to present it a different way? Or do calculations on it?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.   I am not in favour of it at all but are not the decision maker   The fact that its 'stupid' and 'terrible' and we loose all our built in date functions were things I am aware of.  I am wondering if there are any other angles for why this decision should be reviewed?  Thanks once again for your comemnts

Comment: If business is afraid that client can't handle complex data type such as `datetime` properly and wants to use simple `int`, at least use a standard way to store dates as int. One of the widely spread ways to store dates as simple `int` - is unix time. It is always UTC. It is simply a number of seconds passed since `1970-01-01`. You should use `bigint`, not `int` in any case. Still, I would store the date in the database as `datetime` and convert it to and from unix time when talking to client.

Comment: This was talked about and is a great option.  I can offer opinions/pros/cons as a developer however the final decision is not myn.   There has been some great advice on this thread.  Thank you to all for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only integer part of Date, then one of the solution will be just remove the separators in Date Value ex:- '/', '-', ':' and ' ' space from date, and you will get the date with the format you want:-

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE ( '2015-07-16 16:19:00' , '-' , '' ),':',''),' ','')
```

**Output**:- `20150716161900`

<kbd>[See DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ebd7/1)</kbd>

**Update:-**

Use this As per you requirement

```
Select REPLACE(REPLACE((convert(varchar(10),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,101) 
                + convert(varchar(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)),'/',''),':','')
```

And If your column `lastUpdatedDateTimeINT` is INT then its going to throw overflow error, so overcome that you have to change the datatype for that column as Value you going to assign is quite big for INT

Comment: HI there thank you for your input but this fails because hard-coding '2015-07-16 16:19:00' is no use, The replace would need to be done on CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  If I try this of course I get  - Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Comment: so you can convert, not a big deal. What value you have in CURRENT_TIMESTAMP column?

Comment: Sorry I did fully understand.  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is not a column.  lastUpdatedDateTime is the int type column that the value goes into.  I tried this based on your suggestion SET t.lastUpdatedDateTime = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , '-' , '' ),':',''),' ','')

Comment: Yes very nice.  This did give me 7172015094553 so I changed the 101 date format to 111 to give me yyyymmdd and it works great. Thank you.  Do you have an opinion on this intDate requirement?  I will update my original post with you solution and accept this.  Thanks again,a  very good day to you

Comment: Just discovered the 112 format which has no seperators so was able to get rid of one replace.  Original post was updated

Answer (score 2):

If business is afraid that client can't handle complex data type such as `datetime` properly and wants to use simple `int`, at least use a standard way to store dates as `int`.

One of the widely spread ways to store dates as simple `int` - is unix time. It is always UTC. It is simply a number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01. You should use `bigint`, not `int` in any case. Still, I would store the date in the database as `datetime` and convert it to and from unix time when talking to client.

Convert from unix time to datetime:

```
DATEADD(second, [unixtime_value], '19700101')
```

Convert from datetime to unix time:

```
DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', [datetime_value])
```

Instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` use `GETUTCDATE` to get the current UTC time and then convert it to `bigint`:

```
DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', GETUTCDATE())
```

Comment: My response this this is against your comment in the original post